# Setting textview text from a string resource held in an array problem

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

This should be simple, but driving my crazy.

I have the following in my layout, not problems.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birdinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00009c"
    android:text="The Robin is a popular bird"
/>
```

Then I have these arrays which are set up with the list of string resources I have

```
 private Integer[] DetailIds = {            
         R.string.barnaclegoose,
         R.string.barnowl,
         R.string.bewicksswan,
         R.string.blackbird,
         R.string.blackcap_male};
```

So I simply want to do this!

```
    TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birdinfo);
    detail.setText(DetailIds[0]);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

But this causes a force close error.

The string resource looks like this ( without header and footer info of course

```
<string name="barnaclegoose">What a wonderful goose!</string>
```

Added to this problem is if I use the resource directly to the resource

```
detail.setText(R.string.barnaclegoose);
```

For example, I still get a null exception! I'm sure I've done this before, but maybe I'm missing the obvious???

Any ideas appreciated.

( Eclipse, Android 1.5, Emulator with 1.5 )

Comment: are you sure, you can hold Strings within an Integer-Array? ;-)

Comment: post the stack trace of the expcetion

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is very old, but it came up in a search... Anyways, you need to call `setContentView()` before `findViewById()` etc:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birdinfo);
detail.setText(DetailIds[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is for this line `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
at first you must define this this line then setText your textView

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. but if you mean R.string.barnaclegoose for example, this is an integer value for the ID pointing to the string itself in the resource.

Anyway, I finally got it working by just creating the view inline instead of using an resource view.

For example

```
TextView t= new TextView(ctx);
     t.setId(2);
     t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     t.setText(DetailIds[bird]);

    mLinearLayout.addView(t,params);
    mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(mLinearLayout);
```

And that works perfectly.